# Webpack Config multiple entry points error with filter

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've created a React App using create-react-app and have ejected it to get more control over the build process and to turn it into a Browser Extension.

I've got the build to work correctly if there's only one input file, but now as I'm trying to create 2 extra files (which need to be separate from the main as they'll be background files), I'm getting errors while building with no idea why it's happening. I just need to have 1 file with an html page with javascript (react) and the other 2 I just need to be javascript files for the extension functions.

This is the original entry point in the Webpack file:

```
entry: [
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    isEnvDevelopment &&
        require.resolve("react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient"),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
].filter(Boolean),
```

So that the system can spit out separate javascript files, I added in 2 more entrypoints like so:

```
entry: {
    app: [
        isEnvDevelopment &&
            require.resolve("react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient"),
        paths.appIndexJs
    ].filter(Boolean),
    background: [
        isEnvDevelopment &&
            require.resolve("react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient"),
        paths.backgroundIndexJs
    ].filter(Boolean),
    content: [
        isEnvDevelopment &&
            require.resolve("react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient"),
        paths.contentIndexJs
    ].filter(Boolean)
},
```

The appIndex- backgroundIndex, and contentIndex are all defined in the path file and pointing to valid directories.

When trying to run npm run build on this, I keep getting the error:

```
Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

and cannot figure out what is going on with this.

I can't find out anything regarding why this entry point requires the ".filter(Boolean)" or where I can turn it off so it's not required when building.

I thought maybe I could build like this:

```
entry: {
    app: paths.appIndexJs,
    background: paths.backgroundIndexJs,
    content: paths.contentIndexJs
},
```

but this also returns the same error with canot read property 'filter' of undefined.

Out of curiosity I tried the following which I understand merges the files together:

```
entry: [
    paths.appIndexJs,
    paths.backgroundIndexJs,
    paths.contentIndexJs
].filter(Boolean),
```

And the project builds but even then, I don't see any of the functions from the 2 different files show up.

I've created React Apps from scratch and I know that the multiple entry points method works to generate multiple files, but when the project was created using the create-react-app command and ejected, I cannot get the entry point to work as expected.

I think the problem here is not how the entry is being set, but the errors that show when trying to build without the "filter(Boolean)" set on the entry line.

The only difference I can see from the "usual" and the ejected create-react-app is that the "usual" way for the webpack looks like this:

```
// This has worked in the past when making configs from scratch
module.exports = { 
    entry: {
        app: paths.appIndexJs
        background: paths.backgroundIndexJs
        paths.contentIndexJs
    },
```

and ejected create-react-app looks like this:

```
// this is auto generated and unsure if is the reason why it fails to 
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) { 
    const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === "development";
    const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === "production";

    ......

    return {
        entry: {
            app: [paths.appIndexJs]
            background: [paths.backgroundIndexJs],
            content: [paths.contentIndexJs]
        },

        .....
    };
};
```

Unsure if this has any effect on the entry points but I can't see anything else that could be relevant to this.

What is the error message filter(Boolean) and how can I get around this?

Comment: appIndex- backgroundIndex, and contentIndex i think this is getting null, try logging the value where you are trying to do the filter.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS - hi, I know that appIndexJs is valid as it has source code that runs normally (i.e. before trying to update the web config file) but even if I just try to compile that one, I get an error.
How would I go about logging the value where the filters happening? I have no idea where or what's going on with the filter(Boolean) section.

Comment: any progress with this?

Answer (score 2):

found the solution here from [gitmemory](https://gitmemory.com/issue/timarney/react-app-rewired/421/552241572)

The problem was in the ManifestPlugin configuration from CRA. It assumes that the entry point will be called main, the default from Webpack:

```
    // Generate an asset manifest file with the following content:
 // - "files" key: Mapping of all asset filenames to their corresponding
 //   output file so that tools can pick it up without having to parse
 //   `index.html`
 // - "entrypoints" key: Array of files which are included in `index.html`,
 //   can be used to reconstruct the HTML if necessary
 new ManifestPlugin({
   fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
   publicPath: publicPath,
   generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
     const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
       manifest[file.name] = file.path;
       return manifest;
     }, seed);
     const entrypointFiles = entrypoints.main.filter(  // <--- This line here
       fileName => !fileName.endsWith('.map')
     );

     return {
       files: manifestFiles,
       entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
     };
   },
 }),
```

fix was

```
 ...
const entrypointFiles = {};
Object.keys(entrypoints).forEach(entrypoint => {
  entrypointFiles[entrypoint] = entrypoints[entrypoint].filter(fileName => !fileName.endsWith('.map'));
});
...
```